# Google Maps obtain a list of places in current map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to obtain a list of places in current map? For example when I zoom in to below map, there're 7 places. I want to put an image on top of existing place name.

Or, is it possible to replace all the existing names, e.g. "Dynamo Donuts", with clickable images?

http://oi41.tinypic.com/1zvd8ok.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. First of all you have to check if there are any places within the area you want. You can accomplish that with [places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#overview) of google maps. 
Once you have the places (location of the places) you can do whatever you want. You can place markers or images, clickable or not.